# Python Remove dic values by percentage

Tags: python, dictionary, percentage

Hello I have a dict with these values

```
D= {
'a':1000000,
'b':3500,
'c':7000,
'd':867900
'ted':10,
 'tz':3455,
 'tx':7000}

print dict(
    [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if v<=x ]
```

I would like to remove the values from the dic less than 5 % ? How can i achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: please explain yourself a little bit more. what do you mean by 5%? are you talking about the numbers placed in the dict?

Comment: There is a missing comma after the `d` value

Comment: . . . 5% of what? max of `D.values()`?

Comment: @mshsayem I need the values less than 5% of the values in the dic and groupthem

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
>>> x  # any x value 
1000
>>> { k: D[k] for k in D if  D[k] > (.95 * x)}
{'a': 1000000, 'c': 7000, 'b': 3500, 'tz': 3455, 'd': 867900, 'tx': 7000}
>>>
```

Consider only values more then 5% of x

it works as:

```
>>> D
{'a': 98, 'c': 1, 'b': 94, 'd': 9}
>>> x
100
>>> { k: D[k] for k in D if  D[k] > (.95 * x)}
{'a': 98}
>>>
```

Edit: To group less than 5%  and greater and equal than 5% of `x` you can do something like:

```
>>> x
100
>>> D
{'a': 98, 'c': 1, 'b': 94, 'e': 99, 'd': 9, 'f': 100}
>>> d1, d2 = {}, {}
>>> for k in D:
...   d = d1 if D[k] < (.95 * x) else d2
...   d[k] = D[k]
... 
>>> d1
{'c': 1, 'b': 94, 'd': 9}
>>> d2
{'a': 98, 'e': 99, 'f': 100}
>>>
```

`d1` is a new dict with all key, values from `D` where value is < 5%  and `d2` with >= 5% of given `x`.

Comment: is there any way to group the values less than 5% of x and print them along with the remaining values in dict ?

Comment: @user3240059 Yes possible I added an example to create two new dicts from given D.